Latest Compatible version of ChartJs for LWC
My Lwc component's meta-xml has 62.0.
I am wondering what is the latest compatible version of chartjs for lwc in 2024.

You can check it from chartjs website: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

You can check it from the chartjs website. Its version 4.4.6 https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

There's a difference between the latest version and the most recent version that can be used with LWC - it depends on the "module" approach taken in the code base.

I am using the minified version available here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.min.js
I have uploaded it as a static resource and imported it in my LWC, it is working fine. (My meta .xml file also has version 62.0.)
